# read-syntax: `#...=` forms not enabled

Tags: racket

I am attempting to use the `#‹digit10›{1,8}=` and `#‹digit10›{1,8}#` syntax as described in [The Reader](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html#%28part._parse-graph%29), but receive the `` read-syntax: `#...=` forms not enabled `` when I do so:

This code has been run a DrRacket REPL with only #lang racket in the edit area, and in the `racket` program through a terminal emulator with no further arguments or `(require ...)`s.

```
racket> (list #1=100 #1# #1#)
    ==> read-syntax: `#...=` forms not enabled
```

[Reading](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html?q=read-accept-graph#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-accept-graph%29%29) states that the parameter `read-accept-graph` determines whether the reader will parse graph syntax. What's strange is that the parameter is currently set to `#t`.

```
racket> (read-accept-graph)
    ==> #t
```

The following confirms that read-accept-graph changes how the reader reacts to graph syntax:

```
racket> (parameterize ([read-accept-graph #t])
          (read (open-input-string "(list #1=100 #1# #1#)")))
    ==> '(list 100 100 100)
racket> (parameterize ([read-accept-graph #f])
          (read (open-input-string "(list #1=100 #1# #1#)")))
    ==> string::7: read: `#...=` forms not allowed in `read-syntax` mode
```

It seems that the problem is that `read-accept-graph` is bound to `#f` at the moment when racket is reading the expressions, even if it might be `#t` by the time those expressions are executed.

TLDR:
How do I parameterize `read-accept-graph` to `#t` before expressions containing [graph structure](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html?q=read-accept-graph#%28part._parse-graph%29) are read?

Comment: There's a vital missing piece of information in how exactly you're interacting with racket. Is this part of a top-level interaction? Your prompts suggest that it is. Can you provide either a single program that, when run, reproduces the problem, or alternately, a sequence of steps that reproduces the problem?

Comment: FWIW, my strong suspicion is that what you're doing is morally equivalent to trying to change the reader of the code that's currently being read, which would probably be both a security hole and a performance problem.

Comment: @JohnClements Thank you for raising the question about how I was actually running the code --- I've edited my question to clarify how the code was run. I think your suspicion is correct. The reason I believed that I should be able to change read-accept-graph at run time was because of the documentation on Reading Graph Structure (see Alexis King's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blunt answer to your question is that reader graph notation is not allowed in `read-syntax` mode, regardless of the current value of `read-accept-graph`.

However, your question helpfully uncovered two things:

1. The recent rewrite of the reader in Racket v7.0 broke the error message raised when encountering illegal graph notation. The first error should read `` `#...=` forms not allowed in `read-syntax` mode ``, and the second should read `` `#...=` forms not enabled ``, the reverse of what they currently produce.
2. The relevant section of the reference, Reading Graph Structure, does not properly document this difference between `read` and `read-syntax`.

I’ve pushed a fix for both of these problems in [commit `2a667dc`](https://github.com/racket/racket/commit/2a667dc9a8a97adeac49084192ba0773d9619ee4), which will be included in Racket v7.1.

Comment: Thank you! This clarifies (and fixes!) the problem. I would upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.